# Don't understand this "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Code is not properly parsing the table and I cannot find the exact reason why I cannot find the table data for "". Can someone assist?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd 

url = "https://webapps1.cityofchicago.org/activeecWeb/"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")


table = soup.find_all('table')[1]
rows = table.find_all('tr')[1:]

data = {
    'LicenseType' : [],
    'CompanyName' : [],
    'Address' : [],
    'Phone' : [],
    'Expiration' : []
}

for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    data['LicenseType'].append( cols[0].get_text() )
    data['CompanyName'].append( cols[1].get_text() )
    data['Address'].append( cols[2].get_text() )  
    data['Phone'].append( cols[3].get_text() )
    data['Expiration'].append( cols[4].get_text() )

electricians = pd.DataFrame( data )
electricians.to_csv("ChicagoElectriciansData.csv")
```

Comment: Can you post the error message in full with this?

Comment: Please include the full error traceback in your question,as that can help identify where the issue is occurring

Comment: You might also save yourself some work by using pandas `read_html()` instead of bs4

Comment: There is no table data in `""`, I guess that is why you can't find it. On the other hand I don't see any problems with the parsing. Can you elaborate?

Comment: When asking about an error, you should post all the information the error gives you, in particular identify where the error occurs.  However I'm guessing it occurs at `table = soup.find_all('table')[1]`, which is the only list indexing I see.  If true that means that the `find_all` either produced a empty or single element list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are having is because of the last `tr` of that table. You can use `try/except` clause to ignore that error. However using this `.find_all("tr")[1:-1]` also fix the issue which is what I did here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd 

url = "https://webapps1.cityofchicago.org/activeecWeb/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

datalist = []

for row in soup.find('table',class_="gridStyle-table").find_all("tr")[1:-1]:
    d = {}
    d['LicenseType'] = row.find_all('td')[0].get_text(strip=True)
    d['CompanyName'] = row.find_all('td')[1].get_text(strip=True)
    d['Address'] = row.find_all('td')[2].get_text(strip=True) 
    d['Phone'] = row.find_all('td')[3].get_text(strip=True)
    d['Expiration'] = row.find_all('td')[4].get_text(strip=True)
    datalist.append(d)

electricians = pd.DataFrame(datalist)
electricians.to_csv("ChicagoElectriciansData.csv")
```